# How to host android app. I am using mysql and Tomcat server

Tags: java, android, mysql, tomcat, servlets

I have made a simple chat application which communicates with the Tomcat server and tomcat server in turns communicate with MySQL to retrieve users information.

Inside tomcat a servlet is running.

Right Now I am using this on a same network but now I want to publish my app.

For e.x my ip address is 172.24.0.47 and the URL which I am using is
http://172.24.0.47:8080/ChatApp/ and the servlet url mapping is

http://localhost:8080/ChatAppDemo/ChatServlet

everything works fine but when I try to access this URL from a device connected to different network its not working.

Do I have to host it using any web hosting service, or is there any other way?

Sorry I really don't know  what to do next.

Comment: You answered your own question: "everything works fine but when I try to access this URL from a device connected to different network its not working." You need to have a hosted server that's accessible from anywhere in order for others outside of your network to use it.

Comment: So do I have to buy web hosting service like Godaddy.com?

Comment: you must have a public IP address

Comment: If yes what is the procedure can anybody explain?

Comment: @Raj Sharma , Yes, you must have a public IP address as Randyka stated. A hosting service (like GoDaddy) will get this for you.

Comment: I suggest you read how networking works too. This is probably not the only problem you will find (e.g. firewall, NAT...).

Comment: The problem is you use tomcat as server, then normal domain wont do it because its running on php server. i suggest you to use VPS. [GoDaddy](https://sg.godaddy.com/pro/managed-vps?isc=hos1as07&ci=9013) have it too

Comment: thanks all for your answers. Is there any free web hosting? what about 000webhost? Can I use this too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you ahve to use public web hosting services for this.

I think you cna use 000webhost also for this purpose....